# Stacked Bar Chart Using Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to get an amortization schedule chart like [this](http://amortizationcalc.org/) done using Achartengine in an Android app.

Just read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864788/are-multiple-stacked-bar-charts-possible-using-achartengine) after spending a couple of weeks using this charting library. If what I understand is correct, Achartengine stacked bar chart is actually superimposed bar chart. Or is there some other setting I should use to make it work like [Highcharts stacked bar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up tweaking my math to fit the way achartengine "stacked bar chart" works. In this case, I plotted the Principal and the Total (Principal + Interest) amounts series instead of Principal and Interest amounts. Hope this helps others.